# Can we create a dashboard in Grafana to get WAF logs from Azure application gateway?

Tags: grafana, azure-log-analytics, azure-application-gateway, web-application-firewall

I want to collect Azure web application firewall logs and represent them in the Grafana dashboard. I tried doing it using the Azure Monitor plugin but couldn’t get logs. How to do it? Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe exporting the Logs via Export button in Logs blade can help? Assuming Grafana dashboard can consume it.

Comment: How will Grafana consume it?? Can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can export logs via **Export** button in Logs Blade and then consume it from Grafana dashboard by REST API:

see this for reference:
https://community.grafana.com/t/import-dashboard-from-file-via-api/22266

You'll need to manipulate the exported excel to .json so it'll suit the REST POST request.

Comment: The link is about exporting from a Grafana dashboard. My question is how do I create a dashboard that contains WAF logs?